# Python: How do I alias a function with specific parameters?

Tags: python-3.x, function, parameters

I'm trying to assign a function as a class attribute, with specific parameters for the function in different instances of the class. So, if I have two instances `foo` and `bar`, I'd like `foo.func()` to run `function(param1)` when it gets called and `bar.func()` to run `function(param2)` when it gets called.

I've tried something like like this:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

foo = Class(function(param1))
bar = Class(function(param2))
```

But when I run that, the `foo = Class(function(param1))` statement simply executes `function(param1)` instead of creating a new instance of Class. The same issue comes up if I try to alias the function separately, such as:

```
alias_func = function(param1)
foo = Class(alias_func)
```

Is there any way to do this? I'd really rather not define a new function for each instance of the class, but I haven't found anything about it in my searching. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Do you know offhand if there's an equivalent for classes, to make instances with specific parameters?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Are you trying to have a class with a partial function as an attribute, or are you trying to make a partial function that can then make objects?

Comment: The second one, I think. For instance, I'd like to assign var = Class(x=1, y=2, z=3) and then create an instance using "instance = var" instead of "instance = Class(x=1, y=2, z=3)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) normally:

```
from functools import partial

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

abc = partial(MyClass, 'a', 'b', 'c')

test1 = abc()
test2 = abc()

print(test1.x)            # prints a
assert test1 is not test2 # Make sure abc is producing different objects
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always make a wrapper:

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self, *, before=[], after=[], named={}):
        self.before = before
        self.after  = after
        self.named  = named

    def wrap(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        lmerge=self.before + list(args) + self.after
        dmerge=self.named.copy()
        dmerge.update(kwargs)
        return fn(*lmerge, **dmerge)


w1=my_class(before=["before", "more"], after=["after"])
w2=my_class(before=["before"], after=["after"], named={'sep':"..."})

w1.wrap(print, "hi")
w1.wrap(print, "yo", sep="-")
w2.wrap(print, "itadakimasu")
w2.wrap(print, "hasta", "siempre", sep="-")

w3=my_class(named={'before':["more"]})
w4=w3.wrap(my_class, after=["less"])
w4.wrap(print, "zboing")
```